# Vue pagination works only after clicked next page in vuejs-paginate

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a Vue beginner so sorry for dumb question. I want to paginate results in my app, to do so I'm using `vuejs-paginate`. I'm not quite sure why but when the results are delivered from the backend the list of results is empty but when I click on next, everything suddenly shows up.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="!inProgress && loadId" class="row">
    <table class="table table-products">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Style number</th>
          <th scope="col">Sync message</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="product in fetchedSyncResultToShow" :key="product.id">
          <td class="text-bold">
            {{ product.product_code }}
          </td>
          <td class="text-bold">
            {{ product.message }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <paginate
    :page-count="pageCount"
    :click-handler="pageChanged"
    :prev-text="'Prev'"
    :next-text="'Next'"
    :container-class="'pagination'"
    >
  </paginate>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Paginate from 'vuejs-paginate'

export default {
  name: 'BackboneSyncProducts',
  data() {
    return {
      fetchedProductSyncResult: [],
      fetchedSyncResultToShow: [],
      perPage: 10,
      currentPage: 1,
      loadId: null,
      inProgress: false,
    }
  },
  components: {
    Paginate
  },
  computed: {
    pageCount () {
      return Math.ceil(this.fetchedProductSyncResult.length / this.perPage)
    },
  },
  watch: {
    perPage: function (oldArg, newArg) {
      this.pageChanged(this.currentPage)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    pageChanged(pageNumber) {
      let firstElem = Math.max((pageNumber - 1) * this.perPage, 0)
      let lastElem = Math.max(pageNumber * this.perPage, this.perPage)
      this.fetchedSyncResultToShow = this.fetchedProductSyncResult.slice(firstElem, lastElem)
      console.log('fetchedSyncResultToShow', this.fetchedSyncResultToShow)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I think the last part is crucial

```
this.fetchedSyncResultToShow = this.fetchedProductSyncResult.slice(firstElem, lastElem)
console.log('fetchedSyncResultToShow', this.fetchedSyncResultToShow)
```

Console.log shows any result only after clicked `Next`, doesn't log any action before that. How to display results immediately without clicked `Next` page?

[EDIT]
Here is the place where `fetchedProductSyncResult` is populated.

```
watch: {
  loadId(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (!oldValue && newValue) {
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        this.inProgress = true
        fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest(this, newValue).then(response => {
          if (response.data['products_batch']['result']) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            this.fetchedProductSyncResult = response.data['products_batch']['result']
            this.inProgress = false
          }
        })
      }, 1000)
    }
  },
  perPage: function (oldArg, newArg) {
    this.pageChanged(this.currentPage)
  }
},
```

Comment: It looks like you does not fetch your data on initualization. Try to call your pageChanged  method (with 1 as pageNumber parameter) inside mounted callback.

Comment: @Moebius Unfortunately I already did that via `mounted() {
    this.pageChanged(this.currentPage)},` and the result is the same

Comment: Hmm, but where is part where you populate fetchedProductSyncResult at first? This could be a bottleneck if you are trying to do something with fetchedProductSyncResult while it's not fetched yet.

Comment: @Moebius please check updated question.

Comment: @Moebius you were right! I had to add `this.pageChanged(this.currentPage)` inside the at the end of if block where I populate `fetchedProductSyncResult`. Please add your answer and I'll mark it, thanks!